# Python: Loop through a 2D list based on the indices in the list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have this list:

```
ls = [[0, [1, 5], [], 'A'],
      [1, [0, 2, 4], [], 'B'],
      [2, [3, 1], [], 'X'],
      [3, [2], [], 'C'],
      [4, [1], [], 'D'],
      [5, [0], [], 'E']]
```

I want to loop through this list, starting from the row where the last item is "X". In that row the second last item should be 0. After that I want to loop through the rows shown on the second column on that same row (rows 3 and 1), and in those rows the second last item should be 1. Then I loop through rows 0 and 4 and there the second last item should be 2 (At this point there is no need to loop through row 2 because it has already been looped through). This iteration is continued until the entire second last column is filled. So the output should be:

```
[[0, [1, 5], 2, 'A'],
 [1, [0, 2, 4], 1, 'B'],
 [2, [3, 1], 0, 'X'],
 [3, [2], 1, 'C'],
 [4, [1], 2, 'D'],
 [5, [0], 3, 'E']]
```

I tried to do this:

```
def foo(data):
    new_data = data
    for subls in new_data:
        if subls[3] == "X":
            start = subls[1]
            subls[2] = 0
    num = 1
    for num, item in enumerate(start):
        new_data[item][2] = num
        new_start = list(new_data[n][1] for n, i in enumerate(new_data))
        start = new_start
    num += 1
    return new_data

f = foo(ls)
for a in f:
    print(a)
```

But I only get:

```
[0, [1, 5], [], 'A']
[1, [0, 2, 4], 1, 'B']
[2, [3, 1], 0, 'X']
[3, [2], 0, 'C']
[4, [1], [], 'D']
[5, [0], [], 'E']
```

How can I make this work?

EDIT for @SaltySoda

At first this seemed to work but when I try this list:

```
ls = [[0, [1, 7, 8, 9], [], 'E'],
        [1, [0, 2, 10, 11], [], 'C'],
        [2, [1, 3, 12, 13], [], 'C'],
        [3, [2, 4, 14, 15], [], 'C'],
        [4, [3, 5, 16, 17], [], 'C'],
        [5, [4, 6, 18, 19], [], 'C'],
        [6, [5, 20, 21, 22], [], 'E'],
        [7, [0], [], '-'],
        [8, [0], [], '-'],
        [9, [0], [], '-'],
        [10, [1], [], '-'],
        [11, [1], [], '-'],
        [12, [2], [], '-'],
        [13, [2], [], '-'],
        [14, [3], [], '-'],
        [15, [3], [], '-'],
        [16, [4], [], '-'],
        [17, [4], [], '-'],
        [18, [5], [], 'X'],
        [19, [5], [], '-'],
        [20, [6], [], '-'],
        [21, [6], [], '-'],
        [22, [6], [], '-']]
```

It says:

```
a[2] = a[2] - 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

Can you please explain why this happens and how to fix this bug?

Comment: Why we need to start at the third row. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: @Roy Yes, I always have to start at the row where the last item is "X". This is because I want to know how many indices "away" the other row are from this row.

Comment: Is it a given the only one row will have `X` as their last item? Also there will definitely one row with 'X' at the end?

Comment: @Roy Yes, only one row has X as the last item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def foo(data):
    num=2
    new_data = data
    for lists in new_data:
        if lists[3]=="X":
            break
        else:
            lists[2]=num
            num-=1
            ls2.append(lists)
            #ls.remove(lists)
    for times in ls2:
        ls.remove(times)
    
    
    
    x=0
    for lss in new_data:
        lss[2]=x
        x+=1
        ls2.append(lss)
    return ls
    
ls = [[0, [1, 5], [], 'A'],
      [1, [0, 2, 4], [], 'B'],
      [2, [3, 1], [], 'X'],
      [3, [2], [], 'C'],
      [4, [1], [], 'D'],
      [5, [0], [], 'E']]
ls2 = [] #== list where the elements are added
f = foo(ls)
for new_datas in ls2:
    print(new_datas)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. First get the row which ends with `'X'` by using this function.

```
def get_row_X_index(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i][-1] == 'X':
            return i
```

And then iterate through the entire list and fill the second last value of each row by measuring the distance from the row containing `'X'` at the end.

```
for i in range(len(ls)):
    ls[i][-2] = abs(X_row_index-i)
```

Full Code:

```
ls = [[0, [1, 5], [], 'A'],
      [1, [0, 2, 4], [], 'B'],
      [2, [3, 1], [], 'X'],
      [3, [2], [], 'C'],
      [4, [1], [], 'D'],
      [5, [0], [], 'E']]


def get_row_X_index(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i][-1] == 'X':
            return i

X_row_index = get_row_X_index(ls)
print(X_row_index)

for i in range(len(ls)):
    ls[i][-2] = abs(X_row_index-i)

print(ls)
```

It prints:

```
[[0, [1, 5], 2, 'A'], 
[1, [0, 2, 4], 1, 'B'], 
[2, [3, 1], 0, 'X'], 
[3, [2], 1, 'C'], 
[4, [1], 2, 'D'], 
[5, [0], 3, 'E']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(data, rows, num):
    next_rows = []
    next_num = num + 1
    for row in rows:
        if data[row][2]:
            continue
        else:
            next_rows.extend(data[row][1])
            data[row][2] = num
    return data, next_rows, next_num


def foo_whole(data):
    rows = []
    num = 1
    for subls in data:
        if subls[3] == "X":
            rows = [subls[0]]
    for subls in data:
        if not subls[2]:
            data, rows, num = foo(data, rows, num)
    for a in data:
        a[2] = a[2] - 1
    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    old_data = [[0, [1, 5], [], 'A'],
                [1, [0, 2, 4], [], 'B'],
                [2, [3, 1], [], 'X'],
                [3, [2], [], 'C'],
                [4, [1], [], 'D'],
                [5, [0], [], 'E']]
    new_data = foo_whole(old_data)
    for a in new_data:
        print(a)
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain this a little bit? How does it work?

Comment: about foo:it is the most important part,you input the 'data' and the 'rows' you want to change,the 'num' that all above rows should be.it change the data[row][2] to the 'num' and get the "next_num" from data[row][1] then restore into 'next_rows'

Comment: about foo_whole:

Comment: stackoverflow limit the rate of edit，if you still have doubt,I will answer you tomorrow!about foo_whole:1.you get the 'row' where data[row][3] is 'X' 2.set the initial num is 1(the begining ,i set 0 then there is a bug,for fix the bug I use 1 as the first num ) 3.use foo to change the data[row][2] ,at the same time you get the "new row" need to be change, and the "new num" that the new row need to be change to 4.use foo again and again

Comment: fix another bug:def foo_whole(data):
    rows = []
    num = 1
    for subls in data:
        if subls[3] == "X":
            rows = [subls[0]]

    while True:
        data, rows, num = foo(data, rows, num)
        status = 'finished'
        for subls in data:
            if not subls[2]:
                status = 'unfinished'
        if status == 'finished':
            break
    for a in data:
        a[2] = a[2] - 1
    return data

Comment: Hi @SaltySoda, there is still some problems. Could you try to fix it, I don't know why it gives TypeError.

Comment: what kind of typeerror?could you show some details?which line?